# Injecting a route param via an eventlistener in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, routes

I'm trying to find a way for a route to prepopulate a parameter (like setting default) based on the url, without having to provide that parameter to twigs 'url' function.

*You login to a project:
/admin/project/[pr_id]

You have companies:
/admin/project/[pr_id]/company/[co_id]

Then there are orders:
/admin/project/[pr_id]/order/[or_id]*

So in all cases the pr_id is available in the url.

<del>I have setup a twig global for project_id, but this approach requires I then still provide each 'url' function with the pr_id, I'd prefer a way that perhaps a controller is *'projectAware'* and the pr_id can be omitted from twig 'url' func.</del>

<del>I was thinking of somehow injecting the pr_id via an event listener, but using the request and router I can't see a simple way of injecting the parameter.  And if I did manage i'm not sure if the twig 'url' method would still require parsing the pr_id anyway.</del>

**Update**

Cerad's comment made me realise I was looking at this wrong, it isn't the route that needs to prepopulate,  but the twig 'url' function that needs to know of the pr_id.
Since the 'url' function takes a route_name it *will* require the pr_id.  Thus, a custom twig 'url' function is likely the way to go.

Comment: Please provide what you have done so far...

Comment: Not understanding your question.  Perhaps you use a project aware  twig extension to generate the urls thus simplifying the twig template?